# Jquery AJAX update messages during progress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to find any references for this on google without any luck, so Im crawling to the cross asking for help here, even if I know this is a broad question.

Heres the case:

I have a regular ajax cal with jquery:

```
$.ajax({
url : 'url',
...
success : function( d ) { ... }
});
```

And a php-script that takes about 15 seconds to complete, because it runs through several functions.
Simply returning a

```
echo json_encode( array( 'result' => true ) );
```

So, thus far a regular AJAX call.

Now, what Im wondering is, is there a way to put a parameter in the $.ajax to have it listen for messages before the status is complete or the success function is run.
Thereby having it possible for the PHP script to echo out what functions its currently at. Like for example:

functions.php:

```
function getTables(){ 
     echo json_encode( array( 'statusMessage' => 'Gettings tables' ) ) 
}
```

Comment: i think you should use multiple ajax calls

Comment: you can not send progress of server back at ajax so if you must then for each function at server side you should call separate ajax and nest them according to execution order of function.This way you can show progress of each function

Answer (score 0):

Split one big request on a few less requests